# Jupyter & PySpark: How to run multiple notebooks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter

I am using Spark 1.6.0 on three VMs, 1x Master (standalone), 2x workers w/ 8G RAM, 2CPU each.

I am using the kernel configuration below:

```
{
 "display_name": "PySpark ",
 "language": "python3",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python3",
  "-m", 
  "IPython.kernel", 
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "<mypath>/spark-1.6.0",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "<mypath>/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master spark://<mymaster>:7077  --conf   spark.executor.memory=2G pyspark-shell --driver-class-path /opt/vertica/java/lib/vertica-jdbc.jar"
 }  
}
```

Currently, this works. I can use spark context `sc` & `sqlContext` without import, as in pyspark shell.

Problem comes when I use multiple notebooks:
On my spark master I see two 'pyspark-shell' apps, which kinda make sense, but only one can run at a time. But here, 'running' does not mean executing anything, even when I do not run anything on a notebook, this will be shown as 'running'. Given this, I can't share my resources between notebooks, which is quite sad (i currently have to kill the first shell (= notebook kernel) to run the second).

If you have any ideas about how to do it, tell me!
Also, I'm not sure if the way i'm working with kernels is 'best practice', i already had trouble just setting spark & jupyter to work together.

Thx all

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto how will that solve concurrency problems ? :)

Comment: @eliasah this wont for sure. Still great to get some advices :p

Comment: Are you looking to share the sparkcontext ?

Comment: That's not the objective, but would not be a problem either

Comment: If you which to create a context for each notebook, you'll be needed something like Mesos or chronos. The stack will become very complex all of a sudden.

Comment: Well if your sure about it, i'll have to accept. I won't setup such things anyway. Thx for your feedbacks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107854/discussion-between-eliasah-and-pltrdy).

Comment: So, did you reached any conclusion?

Comment: Not really, it wasn't mandatory so we skipped this.

Comment: @eliasah : Could you please explain how to share the sparkcontext among notebooks, from same python kernal. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the database used by Spark to store metastore (Derby). Derby is a light weight database system and can only run one Spark instance at a time.
The solution is to setup another database system to deal with multi instances (postgres, mysql...).

For example, you can use postgres DB.

- Add [postgres](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download) jar in spark/jars
- Add a config file (hive-site.xml) in spark conf
- Install postgres on your machine
- Add a user, password and db for spark/hive in postgres (depends on your values in hive-site.xml)

Example on a linux shell:

```
# download postgres jar
wget  https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.4.jar

# install postgres on your machine
pip install postgres

# add user, pass and db to postgres
psql -d postgres -c "create user hive"
psql -d postgres -c "alter user hive with password 'pass'"
psql -d postgres -c "create database hive_metastore"
psql -d postgres -c "grant all privileges on database hive_metastore to hive"
```

hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hive_metastore</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>pass</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```